# jQuery draggable is not working within a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a draggable div with jQueryUI & Bootstrap. I have created the draggable div, But if drop the draggable div in another div, It is no longer movable. (the second div is not a droppaable one.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="content">

        <div class="row"></div>

            <div class="draggable-divs col-md-12">
                <div class="elem col-md-1">
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move pull-right"></span></a>
                    FILL
                </div>

                <div class="elem col-md-1">
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move pull-right"></span></a>
                    FILL
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="drop col-md-12">
                Drop Me Here
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(
                function(){

                    $('.elem').draggable(
                            { appendTo: 'body' }
                    );

                }
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drop` has higher `z-index` than the `elem`. You're not dropping your draggable items on the div, but below. So then you can't drag it again.

You could set an high `z-index` value for the draggable items to make sure they're above anything else, or set `pointer-events: none;` for the element you drop on.

This should explain what is happening in your code (to see the difference, uncomment one of the styles):

```js
$('.elem').draggable(
    { appendTo: 'body' }                       
);
```

```css
.drop{
    /* pointer-events: none; */  
    background : red;
}
.elem{ 
    /* z-index: 3000; */ 
    background : grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="content"> 
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="draggable-divs col-md-12">
            <div class="elem col-md-12">
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move pull-right"></span></a>
                FILL
            </div>        
            <div class="elem col-md-1">
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move pull-right"></span></a>
                FILL
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="drop col-md-12">
            Drop Me Here
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```